# Saving the contents of a partial in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an application, that upon creating a customer record it will email the customer a welcome email. The message of that email is generated from a partial that merges in various data elements. I want to take the output of that partial and save it into the database so it can be viewed/recalled later.

I tried using the following in my controller.

`@description =  render "new_account_we"`

Which I tried after reading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.

It gave me errors relating to two renders being in the controller as I have the typical respond to in my controller. Which I understand. So I can not render the partial in the controller and I do not want to show it actually on screen so I am stumped as to how to do this.

Can you give me some advice as to the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@description =  view_context.render "new_account_we"`

[explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23626787/4000293)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rails helper `render_to_string` for storing output in a variable. you can see the details [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to save all the contents along with data i.e. data + html, you can use [Rails helper](https://mixandgo.com/learn/the-beginners-guide-to-rails-helpers) to generate email content with data like

in app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def email_contents(some_parameters)
    # Email contents with data
  end
end
```

and in views you can use this like

```
@description = email_contents(some_parameters)
```